# ASP.NET Core database configuration with dependency injection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I ran in to a problem 6 days ago and i still can't figure it out.

I'm setting up a DBContext using DI:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // Add framework services.
    services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

    services.AddMvc();

    // Add application services.
    services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
    services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();
}
```

The database file path is configurered in the appsettings.json

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=xxxx.db"
  },
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

And I'm creating a DBContext like this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext)

```
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
        public DbSet<Network> xxxx { get; set; }
        public DbSet<NetworkEntry> xxxx { get; set; }
        public ApplicationContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationContext> options)
        : base(options)
        { }
}
```

My controller code:

```
public JsonResult Index(ApplicationContext db)
{
    return Json(db.Networks);
}
```

It compiles and runs. If I use the other way of configuring the DB, it works 100% problem free:

```
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=./blog.db");
}
```

The problem I'm having:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Could not create a model binder for model object of type 'xxx.Data.ApplicationContext'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelBinderFactory.CreateBinder(ModelBinderFactoryContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultControllerArgumentBinder.<BindModelAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultControllerArgumentBinder.<BindArgumentsCoreAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>d__22.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeAsync>d__20.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.<Invoke>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.<Invoke>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Any clues?

Comment: Are you injecting this `ApplicationContext` into an MVC model somewhere? You should keep your MVC models clean of any dependencies. An MVC model == data.

Comment: No, my ApplicationContext is not injected to any MVC models based on my understandning. My models only have 1 dependency which is `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` They use strings for data and an int for Key (ID)

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I'm having the same

Answer (score 1):

I have just solved a similar problem.  The problem for me was that I'd misunderstood the dependency injection.  The context doesn't get passed to the Controller method, but to the Controller's constructor.

```
public class NetworksController : Controller
{
    private readonly ChoirAdminContext db;

    public NetworksController(ApplicationContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public JsonResult Index()
    {
        return Json(db.Networks);
    }
}
```